# maximum flow ford-fulkerson analysis

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory, network-flow

I am reading about maximum flows in Introduction to algorithms by Cormen etc.

Ford-Fulkerson algorithm is given below.

FORD-FULKERSON(G, s, t)

```
1  for each edge (u, v) in E[G]

2       do â[u, v]  0

3          â[v, u]  0

4  while there exists a path p from s to t in the residual network Gâ

5      do câ(p)  min {câ(u, v) : (u, v) is in p}

6         for each edge (u, v) in p

7             do â[u, v]  â[u, v]+câ(p)

8                â[v, u]  - â[u, v]
```

While analyzing above algorithm author is mentioned as below.

> The work done within the while loop can be made efficient if we
>   efficiently manage the data structure used to implement the network G
>   = (V, E). Let us assume that we keep a data structure corresponding to a directed graph G' = (V, E'), where E' = {(u, v) : (u, v) belong to 
>   E or (v, u) belongs to E}. Edges in the network G are also edges in
>   G', and it is therefore a simple matter to maintain capacities and
>   flows in this data structure. Given a flow â on G, the edges in the
>   residual network Gâ consist of all edges (u, v) of G' such that c(u,
>   v) - â[u, v] not equal to 0. The time to find a path in a residual
>   network is therefore O(E') = O(E) if we use either depth-first search
>   or breadth-first search. Each iteration of the while loop thus takes
>   O(E) time, making the total running time of FORD-FULKERSON O(E | â*
>   |).

My questions on above text.

1. Can any one please explain above paragraph easy to understand? I think both G and G' is same structually what differnce it makes?
2. What does author mean by "dges in the network G are also edges in G', and it is therefore a simple matter to maintain capacities and flows in this data structure." ?
3. How author came with The time to find a path in a residual network is therefore O(E') = O(E) if we use DFS or BFS?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a heck of a lot of context here, but let's see if I can try to help:

1. Regarding the set E' - if `(a,b)` is in E, then both `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` will be in `E'`, which is why G is not the same as G'.
2. It means it in the sense that there are representative edges in G' for every edge in G, I assume.
3. I think this is just a structural property based on the fact that the edges of G' are a superset of the edges of G.  Without more context I'm really not sure what's going on here.

Comment: No, if (a,b) is in E, then **both** (a,b) and (b,a) are in E'.  In particular, E' is always a superset of E.  On the other hand, $|E'| \le 2|E|$, so $O(E') = O(E)$.

Comment: Whoops!  I should have read more carefully.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

1) $G$ and $G'$ are both *directed* graphs. The edges in $G'$ either coincide with those of $G$ or reverse them. This also answers the second question - lines 7-8 maintain flow conservation and skew-symmetry by sending $\hat{a} [u,v]$ along the reverse edge after each forward edge has $c\overline{a}(p)$ added to it. For three, the augmenting path found in line $4$ is equivalent to the search problem in a graph - using [Depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [Breadth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth_first_search) - First Search, the runtime of this operation is $O(E).$